# How to force regex stop when hits a 'character' and continue from the start again

Tags: python, regex

```
import re
match = re.findall(r'(a)(?:.*?(b)|.*?)(?:.*?(c)|.*?)(d)?', 
'axxxbxd,axxbxxcd,axxxxxd,axcxxx')
print (match)
```

output: `[('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), ('a', '', 'c', '')]`

I want output as below:

```
[('a','b','','d'),('a','b','c','d'),('a','','','d'),('a','','c','')]
```

Each list starts with 'a' and has 4 items from the string separated by comma respectively.

Comment: [Replace all `.` with `[^,]`](https://ideone.com/CHKM2C)

Comment: Where do the empty strings come from?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Thanks. If the text is below: axxxbxd<axxbxxcd, axxxxxd; axcxxx 
They are separated by random character. How to code it.

Comment: is it mandatory that each subitem will start with `a` character? could be there items like `'axxxbxd,xxbxxcxxd,xxbxxxd|axcxxx'` ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, In this case, yes. But I'd like to know how to regex it if it is your case?

Comment: @XiaoboLi What do you mean by a *random character*? Do you know this char beforehand? Is it any non-word char? Then replace all `.` with `\W`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to obtain  several matches from a delimited string, either split the string with the delimiters first and run your regex, or replace the `.` with the `[^<YOUR_DELIMITING_CHARS>]` (paying attention to `\`, `^`, `]` and `-` that must be escaped). Also note that you can get rid of redundancy in the pattern using optional non-capturing groups.

Note that I assume that `a`, `b` and `c` are placeholders and the real life values can be both single and multicharacter values.

```
import re
s = 'axxxbxd,axxbxxcd,axxxxxd,axcxxx'
r = r'(a)(?:.*?(b))?(?:.*?(c))?(d)?'
print([re.findall(r, x) for x in s.split(',')])
print ([re.findall(r, x) for x in re.split(r'\W', s)])

# => [('a', 'b', '', ''), ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), ('a', '', '', ''), ('a', '', 'c', '')]
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/F2QLUL).

If your delimiters are non-word chars, use `\W`.

```
import re
s = 'axxxbxd,axxbxxcd,axxxxxd,axcxxx'
r = r'(a)(?:.*?(b)|.*?)(?:.*?(c)|.*?)(d)?'
print([re.findall(r, x) for x in s.split(',')])
print ([re.findall(r, x) for x in re.split(r'\W', s)])
# => [[('a', 'b', '', '')], [('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')], [('a', '', '', '')], [('a', '', 'c', '')]]
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/O2YzUs)

If the strings can contain line breaks, pass `re.DOTALL` modifier to the `re.findall` calls.

**Pattern details**

- `(a)` - Group 1 capturing `a`
- `(?:.*?(b))?` - an optional non-capturing group matching a  sequence of:

  - `.*?` - any char (other than line break chars if the `re.S` / `re.DOTALL` modifier is not used), zero or more occurrences, but as few as possible
  - `(b)` - Group 2: a `b` value
- `(?:.*?(c))?`

  - `.*?` - any char (other than line break chars if the `re.S` / `re.DOTALL` modifier is not used), zero or more occurrences, but as few as possible
  - `(c)` - Group 3: a `c` value
- `(d)?` - Group 4 (optional): a `d`.

Comment: can you explain how `(?: ... |... )` (alternation group within non-captured group) working in your case?

Comment: thanks, that was interesting. I also wonder would it make a difference, if `(a)` also be optional as `(d)?` group in your pattern. (or vise versa `(a)?...(d)`)? anyway ...

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest It would make the pattern work rather differently. It is not a good idea to have all patterns optional. Besides, I'd rather not change the original pattern logic without OP's feedback.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew Thanks. In my case, each starts with a, but has optional b, c and d.  Using splitting function works. As you said, too many optional might not be a good  idea for my case.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that the crucial sequence `a... b... c... d` should be matched in strict order - use straight-forward approach:

```
s = 'axxxbxd,xxbxxcxxd,xxbxxxd|axcxxx'   # extended example
result = []
for seq in re.split(r'\W', s):           # split by non-word character
    result.append([c if c in seq else '' for c in ('a','b','c','d')])

print(result)
```

The output:

```
[['a', 'b', '', 'd'], ['', 'b', 'c', 'd'], ['', 'b', '', 'd'], ['a', '', 'c', '']]
```